# how to merge some series.`values_count()`?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 pandas series  and I found their `values_count()`.

```
df1:
A. 2
B. 8
D. 5

df2:
A. 1
B. 4
D. 3
H. 7
L. 9

df3:
A. 1
B. 9
D. 3
H. 7
```

then I wanna do this:
bring all of them in a data. If one of them is not in another data set put 0

```
A. 2  1   1
B. 8  4   9
D. 5  3   3
H. 0  7   7
L. 0  9   0
```

Comment: `l = [df1,df2,df3]` and then `pd.concat(l,axis=1,sort=False)` ?

Comment: you could check that website, there are many options that you want to do . https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @anky you can use:-

```
newdf=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
```

after that use:-

```
newdf=newdf.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Now if you print `newdf` you will get your expected output:-

```
A   2   1   1
B   8   4   9
D   5   3   3
H   0   7   7
L   0   9   0
```

Comment: Thank you can I convert A,B,D,H ,L to a new column. it seems it is index now.

Comment: Yes it is index .

Comment: can I make it a new column?

Comment: yeah just use `newdf=newdf.reset_index()` or `newdf.reset_index(inplace=True)`